# Проблема с переменной LPCSTR

Tags: visual-c++

Пишу класс для работы с конфиг файлами, необходимо объявить переменную с именем самого файла, тип должен быть `LPCSTR`, т.к. в функции `WritePrivateProfileString` для имени файла нужен именно он. Объявление выглядит так:

```
class Files
{
public:
    int ReadInt(const char* element, const char* item);
    float ReadFloat(const char* element, const char* item);
    bool ReadBool(const char* element, const char* item);
    void WriteInt(const char* element, const char* item, int value);
    void WriteFloat(const char* element, const char* item, float value);
    void WriteBool(const char* element, const char* item, bool value);

private:
    LPCSTR m_fileName = ".//settings.cfg";
};
```

Но выдает такую ошибку:

> Ошибка    C3646   m_fileName: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения.

Причем выдает ее именно при попытке сделать `LPCSTR`, если изменить, к примеру, на `char` или `const char*`, то на эту строку перестает ругаться.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, у вам нужно прописать `#include <atlstr.h>`. Потому что компилятор не видит инициализацию данного типа.

Comment: Ну так а что такое `LPCSTR`? Почему вы решили, что какое-то `LPCSTR` вообще существует? Откуда вы это взяли вообще?

Comment: Укажите просто `#include <windows.h>`,  @AnT, это виндовый тип https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: Странно, windows.h, вроде, был. Немного пошаманил с инклюдами и все ок стало. Всем спасибо за ответы.